# JSON File Not Recognized While Implementing Universal Links

Tags: ios, json, expo, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I am building a simple app with expo. While implementing linking for android and iOS, I was editing the app.JSON. When I went to rebuild the android build, the terminal gave an error message:

> app.json must include a JSON object.

The terminal doesn't recognize the app.JSON.

I also notice that `applinks:<librexapp.app.link>` appears to not be recognized. What am I missing in my implementation of Universal Links? Code below:

```
  {
  "expo": {
    "name": "Librex",
    "slug": "Librex",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "scheme": "librexapp",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "android":{
      "package": "com.librex.app",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "config":{
        "branch":{
          "apiKey": "Redacted"
        }
      }
    },
    "ios":{
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "associatedDomains":
        [applinks:<librexapp.app.link>],
      "config":{
        "branch":{
          "apiKey":   "Redacted"
      }
    }
  },

    "extra": {
      "firebaseConfig": {
        "apiKey" : "Redacted",
        "authDomain" : "Redacted",
        "databaseURL" : "Redacted",
        "storageBucket": "Redacted",
        "serviceAccount" : "./firebase-private-key.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should quota the string like `"applinks:\<librexapp.app.link\>"`. you can use `[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:obj]` to check the obj is a valid json object.